# Visual Studio 2010: Dependency of Managed project on Native one

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, unmanaged, managed

It is not possible to "Add reference" of managed project on native.

I have found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/1b1b316a-8648-4243-a651-84de51fd2508) that this is possible via "Add item" - reference to dll. But in such case rebuild of dependent projects will not happen.

If I add dependency directly in project files via `<ProjectReference>` item group item, VS shows dependent project in References, but with Exclamation mark (!).

How to add reference of managed project on native one smoothly?
Thanks!

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  Neither the compiler nor the linker know what to do with a DLL.

Comment: yes, that is why I am looking for a way to configure via project dependencies

Comment: Since they don't know what to do with a DLL, *you don't have a dependency on it*.

Comment: yes, that is why I am looking for the way to configure dependency on the project level (two projects are in the same solution), but _not_ via specifying DLL. That is why I described this is question, possibly not clearly enough.

Comment: In fact I have two projects in the same solution and specify dependency one on other. But because one is native and other is managed I don't know how to achieve this. Possibly I misundestood you comment.

Comment: Right-click the project and select "Project Dependencies".  Why you'd want to do this is hopelessly unclear.

Comment: "Project Dependencies". I need dependency for the following: when I run managed project from VS, then I want native project to build also if it was modified (incrementally... or full rebuild - not essential for this question). Is it correct way to obtain this behavior? (this is first time I am working with both managed and native projects in one solution, that is why it is possible that I am trying to do completely wrong things :) )

Comment: There is no mechanism to *not* get it to build if the source code for it was modified and it is in the same solution.  Build + Build or press F5.  It is still massively unclear what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: VS shows native dependent project in References of Managed project with Exclamation mark, I don't understand why. I am working with this solution not long ago and want to clean all warnings.

Comment: That's what happens when you ask it to do things that don't make sense.  Remove it.

Comment: Thanks! this is best answer I can imagine :) It was made in the solution and I tried to figure out why.

Comment: @HansPassant let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2997/discussion-between-sergdev-and-hans-passant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to capture inter-project build dependencies at the solution level where those projects can't actually reference each other, you can set up explicit dependencies inside Visual Studio by right-clicking on the project in question and choosing "Project Dependencies...".

You can explicitly specify the dependencies here (but implicit dependencies will already be greyed out). Adding dependencies in this way will alter one or more ProjectDependencies sections in the solution (.sln) file so that building it from either devenv.exe or msbuild.exe will ensure correct build order.